# .Netcore 2.0 and Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .netcore 2.0 project running on IIS windows 2012.

There is an issue as I can't seem to get virtual directories working that exist outside of the root of the application. This works fine when the files are in the solution:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "images")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/MyImages")
});
```

The below does not however when outside of the root folder -

```
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Configuration["Keys:UploadFolder"]),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/upload")
});
```

The reason for doing this is I have setup CI with octopus deploy. Each time I do a deployment the uploaded files are no longer there without using a virtual directory or creating some powershell script in octopus to copy them all over from last deployment.

Any recommendations or ways of resolving this in IIS with virtual directories in .netcore 2.0?

Comment: From Octopus Deploy description: **enabling you to easily automate even the most complicated application deployments** Shouldn't this tool be putting things where they belong?  It seems pretty unusual to want to access a virtual directory outside the application as logically it doesn't exist (I think).  It'd be one thing if you wanted native file access to some random directory on the server, but it seems you'd be adding a new virtual directory pointing to another directory possibly already virtual to another site or app to do what you want.

Comment: so the upload directory where users upload files should copy all files across each time. What happens if this file keeps growing and growing. Hence to me it makes more sense to use a virtual directory. I am unsure if this is supported in .net core 2.0 though

Comment: If the files are user-content, shouldn't they just be left alone during deployment?  Or is Octopus doing an incorrect backup / restore operation in addition to deployment?  PS - Can't you just add the folder of interest as yet another virtual directory to the app?  (As I was trying to say before)

Comment: the user can either upload a file to a directory in the route of the solution so deploymentfolder1 and then on each deployment copy the contents to deploymentfolder2 so view on the ui or alternatively they can upload to a directory/ however to view the contents of that directory without copying files it would need to be a virtual directory. I cant seem to get .net core 2.0 to view contents of folder outside the route

Comment: Aha!  You're saying the any virtual directory created can't point anywhere on the machine, only to certain sub-directories of the solution.  Got it.

Comment: yes with .net core it does not seem to work when outside of the route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152175/discussion-between-ebyrob-and-user1853454).